# Flask, Python 3, and WebSockets

Tags: python, flask, websocket

How can I serve a websockets endpoint from Flask running on Python 3? This seems near impossible. Note, I do not want SocketsIO or anything like that. Just want to be able, from plain JavaScript following the very simple HTML5 standard, connect to to a Flask endpoint and upgrade it to a Websocket for bidirectional communication. Example JS below

```js
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000/echo");
```

I assumed this would be a simple matter of `pip install`ing the right module, but no. Any ideas? Should I write my own Python module for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is currently not supported. Possible workarounds below

- Go node.js.
- Go python2
- Fix the existing `flask-sockets` module, issue [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets/issues/39).
- Take it on yourself to write a python3 aware python module